SBT test classpath ordering with submodules
I have two modules in sbt: top and common. top depends on common, and common has some configs in src/main/resources/application.conf, that are getting overridden in src/test/resources/application.conf.
When I am running tests from top in intellij, it all works fine. But running with sbt isn't working because main from common comes on the classpath before test.
Basically, for the top-level module (top) it does the right thing, placing test-classes before classes, but for dependencies the order is reveresed:
top/target/test-classes,top/target/classes,common/target/classes,common/target/test-classes
This seems like a bug, but I am mostly interested in some sort of a workaround I could use to get unblocked quickly, preferably without changing the actual code (I know I could rename the file in test for example, and just make Config read that first, but that seems ... icky :/). Any ideas?
I actually found this post that seems to be talking about exactly my issue and offers a solution, but when I tried adding Test / dependencyClasspath ~= { println("FOO"); cp => cp.sortBy(f => f.data.getName ) } to build.sbt (I know this is not the right order, but still should do something), it doesn't make any difference (and doesn't print anything).

Ok, actually looks like the solution suggested in that github issue actually works, I just needed to wrap that call into .settings for each project:
def fixClasspath(cp: Seq[Attributed[File]]): Seq[Attributed[File]] = cp
  .groupBy { case x => if (x.data.getName == "test-classes") 1 else if (x.data.getName == "classes") 2 else 3 }
  .toSeq
  .sortBy(_._1)
  .flatMap(_._2)

lazy val top = (project in file("top"))
 .dependsOn("common" % "test -> test; compile -> compile")
 .settings(Test / dependencyClasspath ~= fixClasspath)

